# Error if i post a canvas and leave the application

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

I am rendering a canvas to a surfaceview in an extra thread which handles the locking and unlocking of the canvas.
Because my apps crashes if i switch to the homescreen with the homebutton (error: nullpointerexception, canvas is null) i make sure before calculating that the canvas is not null.
So i do it like this:

```
    @Override
public void run(){
    while(running){
        Canvas canvas = this.holder.lockCanvas();
        if(canvas != null) {
            this.render.canvas = canvas;
            this.render.RenderOneStep();
        }
        this.holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(this.render.DisplayResult());
        this.view.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

But if i switch to the homescreen i get this strange error:

> 12-19 15:09:52.333  11190-11208/com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 11208 (Thread-1006)
>
> 12-19 15:09:52.387  11190-11208/com.example.standardbenutzer.adelpath A/libc﹕ Send stop signal to pid:11190 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)

Any ideas how i can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown your rendering thread in onStop and start it again in onStart

Not sure if this is going to solve your issue or not

When I do rendering on a canvas I always stop the rendering thread when my activity is destroyed ( onStop or onDestroy ) and start it up again when I re-enter the activity.

I keep a reference to the runnable class doing the canvas lock unlockAndPost logic.
When I exit I call a method on the runnable to end the rendering thread.

In your case changing the "running" variable to false.

The other thing I do is check that the canvas object has a width > 0 and height > 0
I skip the rendering if the canvas has no width or height. I was seeing this on some devices, still not sure why.

I had a similar problem that was caused by accessing view ( not canvas ) information related to the activity in my rendering routine.

Comment: When should i start and stop it?

Comment: i left a comment i think, didn't i?

Comment: How do i recognize if the user re-enters the activity?

Comment: onCreate -> onStart() -> onResume(). Using onStart or onResume should work fine.

Comment: i start the custom Thread in the MainActivity which also implements runnable. In the "run" method of my MainActivity i do this: [link](http://pastebin.com/Q99Z6tBC). But directly after starting my application i now get an NollPointerException on my Canvas in my custom Thread class: http://pastebin.com/TEkRbgKT
But i thought i make sure that the canvas is not null with this code line: this.holder.getSurface().isValid()

Comment: Why does this not work? http://pastebin.com/sfpa6SwW I get: `code java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: canvas object must be the same instance that was previously returned by lockCanvas `